# Nopcommerce - Custom Payment Method's PostProcessPayment not redirecting to Payment Gateway URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I am developing a custom payment method plugin for a Nopcommerce site. This is the the payment processor class code:

```
public class CODBookingPaymentProcessor : BasePlugin, IPaymentMethod
{
    private IShoppingCartService _shoppingCartService;
    private IOrderService _orderService;
    private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    #region Ctor
    public CODBookingPaymentProcessor(IShoppingCartService shoppingCartService,
        IOrderService orderService, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this._shoppingCartService = shoppingCartService;
        this._orderService = orderService;
        this._httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
    #endregion

    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ SOME CODE ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
public void PostProcessPayment(PostProcessPaymentRequest postProcessPaymentRequest)
    {
          // some code
          string url = protocol + host + "/" + "PaymentCODBooking/ProcessInternetPayment";

        _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(url);
    }
```

The breakpoint is coming at last line and `url` is forming correctly. But the page is not redirecting to the `url` when `CONFIRM` button is clicked on Checkout page. It just stays on the page or sometimes empties the cart. It means order is being created without going to payment gateway.

## UPDATE

The redirect is also not working in `ConfirmOrder` action of `CheckoutController`.

```
if (_webHelper.IsRequestBeingRedirected || _webHelper.IsPostBeingDone)
{
    //redirection or POST has been done in PostProcessPayment
    //return Content("Redirected");

    return Redirect("http://localhost:15536/PaymentCODBooking/ProcessInternetPayment");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you everyone for help. Your answers gave me some hint and find the issue. The issue was that I forgot to set `public PaymentMethodType PaymentMethodType => PaymentMethodType.Redirection;`. It was set to `Standard` which caused the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The redirect has to be an action result. For example in controller's action we write like this:

`return Redirect("http://www.google.com");`

Without the `return` keyword it would not redirect.

To redirect from the controller of a plugin check out the similar implementation in the *\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.PayPalStandard\Controllers\PaymentPayPalStandardController.cs* class of the *PayPalStandard* plugin that comes out of the box

Comment: No I want to redirect from `PostProcessPayment`. PayPal Standard plugin is also doing the same in its `PostProcessPayment` in PayPalStandardPaymentProcessor.cs

Comment: I think the `httpContextAccessor` has the current context for redirecting.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to develop a plugin, it's so much better to not change the nopCommerce source code. You can perform the redirection in the plugin itself, don't change the `ConfirmOrder` action of `CheckoutController`. Change your code to this:

```
public void PostProcessPayment(PostProcessPaymentRequest postProcessPaymentRequest)
{
      // some code
      string url = protocol + host + "/" + "PaymentCODBooking/ProcessInternetPayment";

    _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(url);
    return;
}
```

you can find these lines in `ConfirmOrder` action. The application will rich here after the `PostProcessPayment`. The redirection performs here:

```
if (_webHelper.IsRequestBeingRedirected || _webHelper.IsPostBeingDone)
{
    //redirection or POST has been done in PostProcessPayment
    return Content("Redirected");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changes PaymentMethodType to PaymentMethodType.Redirection It will work